# How to stop mouse "pausing"

Tags: windows-xp, mouse, plug-and-play

My Microsoft mouse recently stopped working, so I purchased an [AOpen O-35G](http://usa.aopen.com/products_detail.aspx?Auno=956), plug and play. No software came with it and I was advised to "just plug it in". I did this, and it worked, although some of the more advanced features do not work.

My problem is that now the mouse cursor hesitates occasionally, and then over shoots the target I selected. This never happened before. It seems to happen when I am using the mouse and a browser window reloads.

Does anyone know how to change this? It is very annoying.

XP Pro SP3

Thanks.

EDIT: It is not a problem of dust or a hair. I have contacted the Manufacturere and they are not responding.
I have the mouse attached to my computer via a powered USB hub. I am going to try plugging it in directly to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't going to help you much but there are some shockingly bad mice out there. I'm rather picky with mine and I've come across things like this. I tend to just not use stuff that does that.

Comment: How true. Same with off-brand no-name keyboards. Keyboards and mice are one hardware thing Microsoft does brilliantly.

Comment: You are right, this is not helping. If you were stating that since it seems to be "bad quality", the problem is probably hardware, ok. But for now, you are only telling about your opinion, and not providing an answer. And in this case, this should remain a comment only, under the question.

Comment: I'm selecting this answer for the reasons I said in MY answer to this question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend installing [AOpen's driver for the mouse](http://download.aopen.com.tw/userdownload_List.aspx?RecNo=4487&Model=956) and see if that helps.

Other than that, I would check to see if there is something blocking the optical sensor on the bottom - mine frequently acts strange, and I'll find a single cat hair across the sensor, driving the mouse nuts.

Also try a different mouse pad or surface for the mouse. Some mice are particular about the type of surface they're on, whether they're too reflective, not enough patterns, etc.

If all else fails, I have always enjoyed using Microsoft mice. You can pick up a wireless or wired laser mouse for pretty cheap these days, like the [Microsoft Wireless Laser 5000](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826105187).

Comment: Haaa.. the cat hair on the mouse sensor. Every day ! :)

Comment: I got an updated driver from the Manufacturer. It not only did NOT solve the problem, it removed the ability to "Wheel click" for continuous scrolling. They have not responded to requests for further help. I have sent a specific request to their support team over 72 hours ago. They state that they "will respond within 72 hours".

Answer (score 1):

According to your link, this mouse is said to be ps2 and USB compatible.

Try eventually to plug it directly on a ps2 port (if you have one), to see if the problem wouldn't be from this. I have memories of some Logitech mouse jumping, blocking this way, when it was plugged on usb and not ps2.

In general, give as well a try on another computer, if you have the occasion. If the problem is the same, then probably it's a hardware issue, and it will be hard to fix in another way than sending to mouse back to manufacturer (or seller).

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a ps2 port but I will try to test it in the manners you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my laptop on XP Home SP3 with my USB mouse stalling. After some investigations with process explorer it turned out to be a process called hotkey.exe. This came with my Toshiba laptop. Killing it  fixed the annoying problem for me. I did not really manage to find out how to uninstall it, but you can disable it starting up in msconfig.

Otherwise, start task manager and sort on CPU usage. You can see if any application has a CPU spike just after your mouse ´pause´.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

I finall got a response from A-Open:

"Our mouse is not supported for FireFox".

Cheap mouse.

Comment: Um... you realize thats just a crap reply to divert responsibility from them to firefox? They might as well have said "Our mouse is not supported for computers". Get a decent Microsoft or logitech mouse.

Comment: You didn't even mention firefox in your question. I'm assuming it acts crappy besides just in the browser? Buy another MS mouse. For a software company, they make some damn fine hardware

Comment: So, basically, A-Open admitted "we make crappy hardware and we haven't a clue about how computers work." Helpful, but probably not in the way they intended...

Comment: Absolutely, Martha.