# How to stop mouse from lagging when you move from a stop?

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I recently purchased a [mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013WC0P2A) and upon trying it I find the following problem: When the mouse is stopped and I try to move it just a little bit, it doesn't move at all until I push it far enough and it jumps and overshoots the target. This is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/64065/548799), except that the problem occurs only when moving the mouse from a dead stop, and only when trying to move it just a little bit.

In case it makes a difference, my computer is a lenovo Thinkpad T440p running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to improve that is to go in the control panel to decrease the mouse speed and increase its acceleration.  That way, you can still move a big distance without moving the mouse all over your desk, but it also increases the precision of movement.

Answer (score 0):

Mice have something called DPI (dots per inch) which is a measure of how far the mouse moves on the screen when you move it the same distance on your desk. If you lower the DPI of your mouse, then it should be able to move small amounts without jumping too much.

On the specific mouse you posted, There is actually a button right in the middle of the top of the mouse that allows you to choose between 5 different DPI.

As another answer pointed out, simply decreasing mouse speed and increasing acceleration (or checking "enhance pointer precision") in the Control Panel solves the issue.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?  How you've changed DPI?